# How can I make a function slot in the inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inspector

If I write a line of code saying,

```
public GameObject monster;
```

I would get a space for game objects only in the inspector, right? But what I want is a space for methods only. So basically what I'm picturing is, Step 1: I drag any kind of script to the space in the inspector. Step 2: beside that space is a list of public methods written in the script so If I choose one of them, the method itself would be stored in a variable. Just like the method chosing list in event trigger component.

Comment: Could you provide some code, and check this link I think I know what you mean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57035463/how-to-pass-values-inputted-by-user-in-main-method-to-another-method-in-c/57035533#57035533

Comment: Added some more details!

Comment: `public UnityEvent onClick;` also see [related question on GD.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/139829/123089). Is this what you want?

Comment: @Bob doesn't really look what I would think OP is asking

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55141856/7111561) should give you an example of how to use a [`public UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) correctly